# How do I install a driver for an Atheros AR9285?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, atheros

How to install the driver for Atheros AR9285 in Ubuntu 11.10.

Still no package for 11.10 according to this

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Atheros/AR9285

---

Here is the output of the commands

```
marc@fer-VPCYA1V9E:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 4c:0f:6e:d6:65:cc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.0.0-12-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:d3400000-d340ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Atheros Communications
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c0
       serial: 54:42:49:a2:1f:bc
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:43 memory:d2400000-d243ffff ioport:1000(size=128)
```

And the second command

```
marc@fer-VPCYA1V9E:~$ rfkill list
0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Please have a look at this answer and let me know if it resolves your issue.  Otherwise - add to your question the results `sudo lshw -class network` and also `rfkill list`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get an Atheros AR9285 wireless card working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65779/how-do-i-get-an-atheros-ar9285-wireless-card-working)

Comment: same issue (AR9285, 64bit) under discussion in: http://askubuntu.com/questions/115458/atheros-wireless-card-shows-up-as-two-different-models

Comment: Possible solution: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rfkill/+bug/900030/comments/2 which may resolve this for you.

Answer (score 9):

I fixed it. Edit the following file

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add this

```
blacklist acer_wmi
```

Then reboot and your wifi should work ;)

Comment: This didn't work for me and I'm wonder why would it work? What does the acer_wmi driver have to do with the Atheros AR9285 device?

Answer (score 3):

I have just solved the wireless problem on Lenovo B560. However, I'm a beginner into Linux, and didn't immediately figure that `blacklist acer_wmi` can only be added by running the command:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

The ath9k driver *is* included, and I can verify it's working -- wlan0 exists.  However, the device cannot be switched on in the System Settings.

Mercifully, it was plug-and-play to cable-tether my Dell Streak.

Answer (score 0):

The ath9k is included by default with latest linux Kernal. If you are interested in building latest one on your own. You can Google for `"compact wireless linux driver"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as @fernando with wifi drivers for Atheros AR9285. After spending 6 hours trying editing blacklist, various backports, compat drivers and even once compiling newer kernel version.

`rfkill list all` used to show

```
Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: yes
```

The thing which solved my case was setting the wifi ON using hardware switch.

Try it: Boot into ubuntu in recovery mode and select **enable networking**

Reboot and all is done. I then had `Hard blocked: no` and my wifi started working