# Atheros AR242 wireless not working

Tags: 11.10, wireless, atheros, compaq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help set up Atheros ar242x/ar542x wireless adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78115/help-set-up-atheros-ar242x-ar542x-wireless-adapter)

just did a clean install of 11.10 on a new SSD. and i can't turn on Wi-Fi. Used google and found a number of answers pointing towards interference with acer_wmi ([here](http://sage.bt/tips/get-atheros-ar242x-ar542x-wireless-card-to-work-on-ubuntu.html) for instance).  so i blacklisted that driver and rebooted.  Still no go. I go to Wi-Fi and I can flip the switch to "on" but it is not orange and it snaps immediately back to off.

This is on a Compaq Presario CQ50.  i note that it has an illuminated Wi-Fi button right next to the power button. pushing this has no effect, the light doesn't toggle.  The Wi-Fi did work (under Windows) until the hard drive crashed.

Here is `iwconfig` output:

```
pk@alot_of_ocelot:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

I am happy to post anything else, but as I too am a n00b at Ubuntu, not sure what would be useful.

reddit gold for anyone who can help me!