# Why can't wireless connection be enabled on my Sony Vaio E-Series laptop?

Tags: wireless, connection, vaio, sony

I have built in wireless (with a switch & light on hardware for it) it's a Sony Vaio E-series with Ubuntu running alongside windows 7.

The button in the menu for `enable wireless` is greyed out, and in the "edit connections" window when I click the button to make it `'On'` it turns it `'Off'` immediately while the wireless button is switched on & the hardware wireless light flashes once for 3 seconds.

Wifi works perfectly and the light stays on (solid) when using Windows 7, and it works fine with wired connection on Ubuntu.

Comment: Sounds as if your wireless card is not recognized. What wireless card is it ?

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 2):

Append this line to file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

```
blacklist acer_wmi
```

and your wireless will getup soon.

Answer (score 1):

While you have your wired connection active, try clicking on the System menu, administration and then on Additional Drivers

Run this utility to see if it will automagically hook up your machine with some drivers for that wifi card you've got there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you haven't fixed it yet, look at this link it explains it pretty okay

[How do I install a driver for an Atheros AR9285?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67437/how-do-i-install-a-driver-for-an-atheros-ar9285)

http://marcusvbp.com.br/site/ubuntu-wireless-nao-funciona-no-sony-vaio-vpceg-oh-e-agora-quem-podera-me-ajudar

You have to translate the second link, but with google chrome, that shouldn't be a problem. I'm about to try it on mine right now, wish me luck!

Comment: Don't forget to edit your answer to let us know whether that works out for you. I think you're getting close to the line between "legitimate answer" and ["me too"](http://askubuntu.com/faq#deletion) response based on the current revision.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the battery, wait 30 seconds, slide the switch to the ON position, reinsert the battery, and turn the Vaio on.

Not only that, risk it all by sliding the switch OFF (the light will go out and WiFi will be disabled ) then ON again … and it should come back to life.