# Atheros AR9285 does not work on 11.10

Tags: 11.10, networking, wireless, atheros

I have installed the 11.10 and everything went smoothly. The wifi card was automatically detected and connected to my wifi network, downloaded all the required files.

But after the restart, I can't use any wireless connections (only the cable), as it says that the device is not supported (or handled).

How can I fix this problem?

```
user@laptop ~ $ lspci | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter   (PCI-Express) (rev 01)

user@laptop ~ $ uname -r
3.0.0-15-generic

user@laptop ~ $ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

user@laptop ~ $ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

user@laptop ~ $ sudo lsmod |grep ath
ath9k                 127538  0 
mac80211              462092  1 ath9k
ath9k_common           13839  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              312914  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    24067  2 ath9k,ath9k_hw
cfg80211              199630  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
```

Edit:

```
 In the network manager I don't see any wireless networks and the Wireless network option is grayed out.
```

I have installed `wicd-daemon`. It shows all the available wifi networks and the connection works fine.

But how can I make it to work with the Network Manager? It's tray notifications are pretty convenient.

Comment: Well, the kernel module is loading...which is good.  Where isn't it recognizing?  NM?  wicd?  More info required.

Comment: @aking1012 See my edit.

Comment: It looks like this is relevant: https://plus.google.com/100205841367942959953/posts/h45ECH9TSgc  
It's not a solution, but the gist of it is wicd and nm talk to the kernel differently recently.

Comment: Here's another link on ubuntuforums: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1866335 ... seems like a problem with the driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should blacklist the acer_wmi kernel module as explained in this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67437/how-do-i-install-a-driver-for-an-atheros-ar9285). There is already a bug report for this problem for the kernel [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16570).