# Unable to connect to wireless on 13.04

Tags: wireless, networking, ath9k

Network manager can see my home network and says strength is ok or even good, but won't connect. Sometimes it asks for my password repeatedly but usually it just tries to connect for a bit and then gives the "disconnected -- you are now offline" message. Other computers have no problem connecting, and my computer has no problem connecting to other networks.

I've tried:

- Turning the router off and on again
- Turning the computer off and on again
- Deleting the connection information, stopping and restarting network manager, and re entering the information as if it were a new connection
- Deleting the connection, rebooting, adding it again
- Making sure the password is correct
- Toggling settings like "available to all users" and "connect automatically"
- **edit:** adding the line `blacklist acer_wmi` to the file blacklist.conf, as in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67437/how-do-i-install-a-driver-for-an-atheros-ar9285#68876)

... and none of these have helped.

**edit 2** I don't currently have access to my router via ethernet cable, so doing `route -n` from my command line isn't possible right now. I am using a mac that has no trouble connecting to the internet, so following the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782658/how-to-get-default-gateway-in-mac-osx, I ran `route -n get default` from the mac. Does that give the required information? The output was

```
$ route -n get default
   route to: default
destination: default
       mask: default
    gateway: 192.168.1.1
  interface: en1
      flags: <UP,GATEWAY,DONE,STATIC,PRCLONING>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500         0
```

I've been using this network for several months, and this problem seems to come up every couple of weeks, lasting a couple of days at a time, and suddenly start working again for no discernible reason.

Some outputs of the commands that might be relevant:

The output of `iwconfig` was

```
eth0    no wireless extensions

lo      no wireless extensions

wlan0   IEEE 802.11bgn ESSID:off/any
        Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power=16 dBm
        Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
        Power Management:on
```

The output of `lspci` was

```
:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
09:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
0b:00.0 USB controller: Texas Instruments TUSB73x0 SuperSpeed USB 3.0 xHCI Host Controller (rev 02)
```

Any ideas? Any further information I should provide?

Comment: Can you try the answer here and edit your question with the results? http://askubuntu.com/questions/67437/how-do-i-install-a-driver-for-an-atheros-ar9285#68876

Comment: @JorgeCastro, I tried that answer and wireless still doesn't work, so I added it to the list of things that didn't work above. Would any of the commands be expected to give a different output now such that I should repost them?

Comment: Check if your router uses TKIP for WPA/WPA2 encryption. If not try set it to TKIP.

Comment: @linuxk, how do I check that?

Comment: This steps requires you to have direct access to the wifi router. 
Try connecting your computer to the router using ethernet cable . Open up terminal and type route -n.  Post the output of route -n.

Comment: @linuxk thanks. I edited the question; does that help?

Comment: cool! Now open any browser and paste this in URL column  http://192.168.1.1  This will bring you to router setup page.