# Toshiba Portege z835 wifi not working @ 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, iwlwifi, toshiba

I need some help to get my wifi card working. I migrated from w7 to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and my problem started.

My wireless card is enabled into BIOS settings, and I've already pressed Fn+F8 to turn it on.

When looking too lspci -knn i've got this:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:0091] (rev 34)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 AGN [8086:5201]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Checking dmesg | grep iwlwifi i've found this message:

```
RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
```

I suspect that this is a indicative o the problem I'm facing.

I've already tried to do some sequences such as:

```
rmmod iwldvm
rmmod iwlwifi
rfkill unblock all
modprobe iwlwifi
modprobe iwldvm
```

My 'rfkill list all' output is:

```
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

And finally for reference these are my loaded modules:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69632  0
bnep                   20480  2
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  4    uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
arc4                   16384  2
iwldvm                233472  0
mac80211              737280  1 iwldvm
intel_rapl             20480  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
coretemp               16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          40960  3
snd_hda_codec         135168  4     snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
kvm_intel             172032  0
snd_hda_core           73728  5     snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
kvm                   540672  1 kvm_intel
snd_pcm               106496  4     snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwldvm
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
lpc_ich                24576  0
mei_me                 36864  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
soundcore              16384  1 snd
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
serio_raw              16384  0
toshiba_acpi           40960  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 toshiba_acpi
wmi                    20480  1 toshiba_acpi
toshiba_bluetooth      16384  0
toshiba_haps           16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
jitterentropy_rng      16384  0
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
algif_skcipher         20480  0
af_alg                 16384  1 algif_skcipher
dm_crypt               28672  2
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  1127
i915                 1208320  3
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  566     ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 i915
psmouse               131072  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  2
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
e1000e                237568  0
drm                   364544  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
sdhci_pci              28672  0
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_pci
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
video                  40960  2 i915,toshiba_acpi
fjes                   28672  0
```

This is my current kernel version:

```
Linux isengard 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to reset BIOS to defaults.

Comment: I've already tried =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Toshiba_portege_z830) you can *cycle* through wifi and bluetooth with Fn+F8.

Can you try a solution mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67437/how-do-i-install-a-driver-for-an-atheros-ar9285) ?

```
The thing which solved my case was setting the wifi ON using hardware switch.
Try it: Boot into ubuntu in recovery mode and select enable networking
Reboot and all is done. I then had Hard blocked: no and my wifi started working
```

For more on this laptop see also [here](http://www.linlap.com/toshiba_portege_z830-10f).

Comment: I've tried them all, but unfortunately I still have no WiFi. When trying to start networking from recovery boot option, firstly I've got an error: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory, then I created it (as an empty file),  rebooted and now when trying the same option the process hangs with the message: "Trying to start Network manager". If Ctrl C is pressed then is possible to return to recovery menu. =(

Comment: Well... I've found a **bizarre solution**. I have a bootable USB with tails linux which already have been used in the past and the wifi worked well in such occasion. When trying to use it now, it behaves like in ubuntu (wireless card hard blocked). Then I remembered that before installing ubuntu I was backuping my W7 partition, and turned off all wireless connecttions (wifi+bluetooth) using Fn+F8. Based in this fact, I've restored my W7 image, booted and activated Wifi using the Fn key. Then I've tryied the live linux distro again and this time wifi is working perfectly.

Comment: A very interesting point, or maybe the **most bizzare** point, is that to get Fn keys working into W7 I need to have the "Toshiba Value Pack Applications" installed (there's an app into this package which is responsible for keeping track of 'Fn' press and show a menu, similiar to ribbon bar, with all options to turn on/off.). Without this package I'm not able to turn wifi on. It seems that there is some command (known by this app) which is sent to hardware to block/unblock wireless card functioning.

Comment: That is a surprising result. Good that you are sharing it. Maybe you can update your question [Solved] and point to your comments or update the question content ? That could be nice for other people who have the same problem ?